# Closing more than one Autohotkeys applications

Tags: c#, autohotkey, kill-process

I have 4 applications and I have to use 4 different autohotkey exe applications for always on Top future. However, I would like to close all of them or kill their process.
I tried using `ESC::ExitApp`, `Process.Kill()` function as well, but only one of them is closing.

Here is my code:

```
#SingleInstance Force

WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Toggle, Bot
Winset, Style, -0xC00000, Bot

^!p::Pause
*ESC::ExitApp
return
```

Other applications are the same but different Windows Title name.

```
Process[] bottom = Process.GetProcessesByName("bottom");
//MessageBox.Show(workers.Length.ToString());
foreach (Process bot in bottom)
{
    bot.Kill();
    bot.WaitForExit();
    bot.Dispose();
}

Process[] left = Process.GetProcessesByName("left");
//MessageBox.Show(workers.Length.ToString());
foreach (Process l in left)
{
    l.Kill();
    l.WaitForExit();
    l.Dispose();
}

Process[] right = Process.GetProcessesByName("test1");
//MessageBox.Show(workers.Length.ToString());
foreach (Process r in right)
{
    r.Kill();
    r.WaitForExit();
    r.Dispose();
}

Process[] top = Process.GetProcessesByName("top");
//MessageBox.Show(workers.Length.ToString());
foreach (Process t in top)
{
    t.Kill();
    t.WaitForExit();
    t.Dispose();
}

SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
```

According to above code, I tried to kill 4 apps but only one is closing. Plus I cannot see in TaskManager running autohotkeys.exe files.Is there any way
to turn off or close all **autohotkeys.exe** files? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you have multiple AHK scripts? They could just be one script? But anyway, your hotkey is only being captured in one script because you're consuming the key press as it happens. The keypress will only be captured by one script. You could just use the [`~` modifier](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) in your hotkeys so the keypress wont be consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WMI from windows to do that.

```
ESC::

    Query := "Select ProcessId, CommandLine from Win32_Process where name = 'Autohotkey.exe'"
 
    for process in ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery(Query, "WQL")
        process, close, % process.ProcessId
Return
```